# Odoo 10 how to pass field data from sale.order to stock.picking

Tags: python, odoo-10, erp

I have a field in header of sale order and need to pass those field value to stock picking.
How do we do that in odoo 10
Can you guys please help

Answer (score 1):

for this problem you can create a new module and add this fuction in button

```
def action_create_pq(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    i = 0
    seller_ids = []
    po_id = {}
    for sale in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        l_ids = self.pool.get('sale.order.line').search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', sale.id)])
        for line in self.pool.get('sale.order.line').browse(cr, uid, l_ids, context=context):
            if line.product_id.seller_ids.id: 
                product = line.product_id.id  
                qty = line.product_id.seller_ids.min_qty
                price = line.product_id.seller_ids.price
                partner_id = line.product_id.seller_ids.name.id
                uom = line.product_uom.id
                date_order = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                if partner_id not in seller_ids:
                    seller_ids.extend([partner_id])
                    po_id[partner_id] = self.pool.get('purchase.order').create(cr, uid, { 
                                                                              'origin': sale.name,
                                                                              'date_order': date_order,
                                                                              'partner_id': partner_id,
                                                                              'pricelist': line.price_unit,
                                                                              'state': 'draft',
                                                                              'shipped': 0,
                                                                              'invoice_method': 'order',
                                                                              'invoiced': 0,  
                                                                              'company_id': self.pool.get('res.company')._company_default_get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order', context=None),
                                                                              })


                po_line_id = self.pool.get('purchase.order.line').create(cr, uid, {
                                                                                    'order_id': po_id[partner_id],
                                                                                    'name': line.name,
                                                                                    'product_id': product,
                                                                                    'product_qty': qty,
                                                                                    'state': 'draft',
                                                                                    'invoiced': 0,
                                                                                    'partner_id': partner_id,
                                                                                    'date_order': date_order,
                                                                                    'product_uom': uom,
                                                                                    'price_unit': price,
                                                                                    'date_planned': date_order,
                                                                                    })

    return True;
```

Comment: Hi developper i have found the solution for this. we can pass data in "_prepare_procurement_group(self):" method in sale_order

Comment: Good that you found the solution
If you would write what is the solution to benefit others

Comment: Odoo use following functions to pass value from sale_order to delivery_order: "_prepare_procurement_group" for Header values(i.e stock_picking) and "_prepare_order_line_procurement" for line values(i.e stock_move)